# Selecting distinct elements from a JQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a JQuery autocomplete field from which I want to select multiple elements (sequentially) and place them in a div so that I can retrieve them later.  This all works.  The problem is that if I select an element I already have selected I don't want that to appear in the div.  The code I have so far does a **contains** search but I require an exact match.  How do I change the following code to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {

                function locationLog(message) {
                    if (!$('#locationLog div:contains(' + message + ')').length) {
                        $("<div/>").text(message).appendTo("#locationLog");
                        $("<br/>").text("").appendTo("#locationLog");
                        $("#locationLog").scrollTop(0);
                    }
                }

                $("#Location").autocomplete({
                    source: "/Results/GetLocations",
                    minLength: 1,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        if (ui.item != null)
                            locationLog(ui.item.value);
                    }
                });
            });
       </script>
```

Comment: on the select function once user selected after that remove that elemnet from your autocpmplete list

Comment: that's a little more complicated, but yes that is a way to do it.

Comment: if you can provide fiddle it will be easy for helpers

Comment: It all works its just that I need to replace contains with exact match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
var test = '/^'+message+'$/g';
if ($('#locationLog div').text().match(test).length === null)
```

Update: must check against null instead of 1 for correct logic...